# Throttled parallel task execution in async select statement with strange behaviour

Tags: c#, async-await, semaphore

In my app I want to add lets say 20 devices starting on port 10 by using a function `AddDeviceAsync` that takes a `template` as parameter which is used for creating the actual device with the name `template.Name` by contacting port `port`.

I am using SemaphoreSlim to prevent exhausting system by trying to add to many devices simultaneously.

```
using (var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10))
{
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(startPort, devicesCount).Select(
             async port =>
                        {
                           try
                            {
                                await semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                                template.Name = $"{device.Name} {port}";
                                template.CommunicationSettings.Port = port;
                                await this.equipmentNewApplicationService.AddDeviceAsync(template).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                semaphore.Release();
                            }
                        });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Something is wrong with my code though because as soon as throttling kicks in (`deviceCount` = 20)

Some devices share their name:

```
DeviceName-10
DeviceName-11
DeviceName-12
DeviceName-13
DeviceName-14
DeviceName-14
DeviceName-14
DeviceName-17
```

Note: only device name is wrong - the devices are connected on the correct port.

I suspect this to be somehow connected to the `async closure` in the `select` but I really cannot figure it out.

Comment: Where is `template` declared? And `device`? Is there a reason your using variables declared in an outer scope?

Comment: template is declared right above the code.

Comment: Is there a reason for that? Looks like you have a race condition, where multiple threads are updating the same variable.

Comment: oh boy how could I miss that! obviously this is caused by concurrent updating of template object. I will refactor so that AddDeviceAsync takes values instead of template reference

Comment: Or create a new template each call

Comment: Previous implementation was not concurrent and parts of template are actually shared which smells to me.

Comment: @yBother if I wanted to throttle concurrent executions I'd use an ActionBlock with a DOP=10 rather than roll my own. Or pass the *DOP* to `Enumerable.Range()` and create 10 worker tasks to load from the data source in a loop. Not start all tasks at once and try to throttle them afterwards

Comment: thx @PanagiotisKanavos I will look in to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no reason to declare `template` in outer scope (and it doesn't appear that there is), then move it inside your `Select`:

```
using (var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10))
{
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(startPort, devicesCount).Select(async port =>
    {
        try
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();

            var template = new Template
            {
                Name = $"{device.Name} {port}",
                CommunicationSettings.Port = port
            };
            await this.equipmentNewApplicationService.AddDeviceAsync(template);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Because `Select` is spawning multiple tasks, which may run on multiple threads, there would otherwise be a race condition trying to update `template`.

Also, the use of `ConfigureAwait(false)` is superfluous inside the lambda, as there isn't any risk of deadlock.